# Iterate over elements retrieved from database Ruby/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drag-and-drop

I am dealing with this issue and certainly do not know how to solve it. I probably have chosen the wrong approach but let me explain it a little bit more. Certain information is being retrieved from my SQLite database, such info is used to build a div structure in my DOM. This div structure represents an item from a store and each element should have attached an action, I do it using some JS. This is how it looks by now:

**HTML5:**

```
<!-- Iterates over all activities retrieved from database -->

    <div class="row"  id="activity" draggable="true">
        <% @activities.each do |activity| %>

        <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
            <div><%= image_tag activity.picture_url, :class => "img-style"%></div>

            <div class="panel img-panel" >
            <h5><%= activity.title %></h5>
            <h6 class="subheader"><%= activity.price %></h6>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <% end %>
    </div>

<!-- ends iteration -->
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function() {
   var activities = document.getElementById("activity");
   console.log('Length: '   + activities.length);

   var count = 0;
   for (act in activities) {
     var activity = activities[act];
     count++;
     console.log(count);

     activity.addEventListener('dragstart', activityDraggingStart, false);
     }

  function activityDraggingStart(e) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
};
```

So the problem lies in the JS code:

- First of all, length returns an undefined because it's an object but it should be an Array, should't it?
- Secondly, if the database has only three records and I use the count variable it displays more than 200 which is awkward since it is supposed to loop only three times.
- Last but not least, I want to add an action to the retrieved element because I'm trying to work my way out through a drag and drop feature but I can't because apparently activity is a NodeList of DOM elements and only each element have the addEventListener.

What should be done in this particular case? What would be the best approach? What basically I'm trying to achieve is adding the event listeners to my "activity" div, in order to do some stuff when the 'dragstart' & 'dragstop' events happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think one problem might be you have multiple elements with the same id name. trying changing it to a class.

the way I did it was to loop over the rows and add the jquery ui draggable to each.

here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0wnwt29j/1/

```
 $(function () {

     var numItems = $('.activity').length;
     $('#myspan').text('num of activities: ' + numItems);

     $(".row").each(function (index) {
         var myelement = $(this);
         myelement.draggable({
             start: function () {
                 myelement.addClass('blue');
             },
             stop: function () {
                 myelement.removeClass('blue');
             }
         });
     });


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your first problem is that you are trying to call .length on an ID, which by default, should only be one item. If you are trying to get an array of all your activities that are listed, I would take the ID to a class and move your loop outside of all your divs, for example

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <div class="row activity" draggable="true">

    <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      <div><%= image_tag activity.picture_url, :class => "img-style"%></div>

      <div class="panel img-panel" >
      <h5><%= activity.title %></h5>
      <h6 class="subheader"><%= activity.price %></h6>
                </div>
    </div>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Secondly, the reason it's displaying 200 is because, since it's only one item (because of "getElementByID") it's counting the number of characters in a string, change that bad boy to "getElementsByClassName."

and third... Well... changing these may fix it.... But I'm not totally certain. Anyway, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your example activities is not an array it's an element, it has no length.

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish but try:

```
var activity = document.getElementById("activity");
 var activities = activity.children;
```

Or

```
 var activity = document.getElementById("activity");
 var activities = activity.childNodes;
```

or for each class e.g panel/ columns or whatever:

```
var activity = document.getElementById("activity");
var activities = activity.getElementsByClassName('panel');
```

Id's do not directly return array-like objects.

Answer (score 0):

All of your troubles are due to the misuse of html attribute `id`.

**Answer to question 1**

Because an `id` is an identity of a single DOM element, a single webpage should not contain 2 or more DOM elements with the same id.

You can change

```
<div class="row" id="activity" draggable="true">
```

to

```
<div class="row" class="activity" draggable="true">
```

and select them by

```
document.getElementsByClassName('activity');
```

**Answer to question 2 and 3**

Since `document.getElementById()` returns only one DOM element, you are traversing through its 200+ properties, and that's why the number of your `count` variable is, and why you can't attach event listener to them. If you've changed your code according to the latter answer, then it should be fine.